# Mplabx ICD3 PIC18f67k40 programming fpga failed

Tags: programming, mplabx

I'm trying to program my PIC18F67K40.  The part is not listed in Mplab 8.92.
Installed Mplab X, but my ICD3 will not work.  I used the switcher program and it says it was successful.  Mplab X sees my ICD3 and sees its serial number.  When I try to program, it tries to install new ICD firmware.  After downloading the new firmware, it tries to program the ICD3.  The error message I get says 
"The FPGA has failed its selftest.  MPLAB will attempt to download the latest firmware.  Please do not disconnect."  Mplab repeats this forever...

I will post this on the Microchip forum, but am now waiting to be approved by moderator.

Comment: Sounds like your ICD3 is knackered.

Comment: I move it back to Mplab 8.92 and select PIC18F2550 and it re-programs just fine.  If 8.92 had the part listed, I guess it may work.  I did try a similar part PIC18F67K22.  Firmware remains the same PIC18F ver. 1.28.90

Comment: unplug the ICD3 from the PIC and see if you can get it to respond, or plug into a known working board. If it still doesn't work then get a new ICD3

Comment: Yea, did the USB unplug reset.  It works when I go to Mplab 8.92 and select 18F2550.  It load the correct firmware.  The part I'm trying to use is the 18F67K40 and it is NOT listed in 8.92.  It's listed in Mplab X, but has issue uploading the firmware to the ICD3.

Comment: There comes a little testboard with the ICD3. Try to test the ICD3 with this board in MPLABX.